# Pandas advanced: How to create multi-index dataframe with nlargest 3 and nsmallest 3 values after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering how to create a mulit-index pandas dataframe which as two top level columns `nlargest_3` and `nsmallest_3` and have the corresponding country and counts in each columns.

## Congratulations

Date: Jan 1, 2020
My happy new year (or in fact happy new decade) congratulations to that genius mind who can successfully answer this question.

## Setup

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(100)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': np.random.choice(list('abcdefgh'),size=(1,1000))[0],
    'count':np.random.choice(range(10),size=(1,1000))[0]

})

print(df.head())
```

## Required

```
# this should be multi-index pandas dataframe
nlargest_3   n_smallest_3
d 140         a 112
c 135         b 116
h 128         f 120
```

## Done so far

```
df.groupby('country')['count'].count().agg(
    [lambda ser: ser.nlargest(3),
     lambda ser: ser.nsmallest(3)]).fillna(0).pipe(print)

   <lambda>  <lambda>
d     140.0       0.0
c     135.0       0.0
h     128.0       0.0
a       0.0     112.0
b       0.0     116.0
f       0.0     120.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
pd.merge(
    df.groupby('country')['count'].count().nlargest(3).reset_index(), 
    df.groupby('country')['count'].count().nsmallest(3).reset_index(), 
    suffixes=["_largest", "_smallest"], 
    left_index=True, right_index=True, 
    how="outer"
).set_index(["country_largest", "country_smallest"])
```

Output:

```py
                                  count_largest  count_smallest
country_largest country_smallest                            
d               a                           140             112
c               b                           135             116
h               f                           128             120
```

Comment: Wow, this does the magic. I have been trying to get this from the morning (9 am to 1 pm) still could not manage to get this. Thanks a lot and happy new year.

Comment: Haha, no worries :) thanks, happy new year to you too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You almost get there with your codes. You just need to use dictionary of funcs on  `Series.agg` instead of list of funcs. Using your codes

```
(df.groupby('country').count()['count']
                      .agg({'nlargest': lambda x: x.nlargest(3).reset_index(), 
                            'nsmallest': lambda x: x.nsmallest(3).reset_index()}))

Out[1870]:
  nlargest       nsmallest
   country count   country count
0        d   140         a   112
1        c   135         b   116
2        h   128         f   120
```